# XSLT Mapping Based on index withou loop

Tags: xslt-2.0

I wnat to map array element based on index without using loop in xslt.

I have below xml.

```
<MpGroupItem>
    <MeasurePoints>
        <MeasurePointItem>
            <Measures>
                <MeasureItem>
                    <Result>2</Result>
                </MeasureItem>
            </Measures>
            <MeasureLimit>
                <CurveLimit>
                    <CurveLimitItem>
                        <X>1</X>
                        <Y1>1</Y1>
                        <Y2>1</Y2>
                    </CurveLimitItem>
                    <CurveLimitItem>
                        <X>2</X>
                        <Y1>1</Y1>
                        <Y2>1</Y2>
                    </CurveLimitItem>
                </CurveLimit>
                <CurveYUnit/>
            </MeasureLimit>
        </MeasurePointItem>
    </MeasurePoints>
</MpGroupItem>
```

I want map the value of element X from first occurence of CurveLimitItem.
I am using below xslt code but not working.

```
<xsl:for-each select="MpGroups/MpGroupItem">
    <xsl:for-each select="MeasurePoints/MeasurePointItem">
        <xsl:for-each select="Measures/MeasureItem">
            <InputValue>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space((MeasureLimit/CurveLimit/CurveLimitItem/Y1)[1]"/>
            </InputValue>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any kind if help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Consider to show us the result you want to output for the input sample you have shown and then to explain with some text what kind of mapping you want to achieve.

Comment: Result XML: <Input value>1<Input value/>

Comment: Well, `(//CurveLimitItem)[1]/X` gives you the child element `X` of the first `CurveLimitItem` in the document. Not sure what you were trying to achieve with all those `for-each`s.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I will check if it work.

Comment: Thanks Martin, It's working for me...